# Best way to find free space in sql server databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to be able to find out how much space is left in my database files so that I can know when to increase the space so it doesn't do it when the application is running hard out.

I would prefer to be able to script this so I can run it across multiple databases ion a regular basis.

I have SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 databases but I would prefer to be able to run the same script across both.

I can use Management Studio to do this manually on 2005 databases, but not on the 2000 databases.

Comment: What's the problem with letting the server doing it when it's "hard out"?

Comment: The sql server basically stops while the files extend.   This is because there is nowhere to write any information.

Comment: That was SQL 2000, perhaps the newer version do it better

Answer (score 15):

Try `sp_spaceused`:

> Displays the number of rows, disk
>   space reserved, and disk space used by
>   a table, indexed view, or Service
>   Broker queue in the current database,
>   or displays the disk space reserved
>   and used by the whole database.

I believe that this was present in SQL Server 2000, but I can't prove it.  It works in 2005 and 2008.

And you can peek at it with `sp_helptext`, if you want to tie it into some server-side logic.

**EDIT**: expanding on my comment below, and with thanks to the original contributor at http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=82359, here's a way to break down usage by file:

```
select
      name
    , filename
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round(a.size/128.000,2)) as FileSizeMB
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)) as SpaceUsedMB
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round((a.size-fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)) as FreeSpaceMB
from dbo.sysfiles a
```

Comment: Is there something similar to get free space in database files?

Comment: The data you want is is dbo.sysfiles.  Try the statement at the end of this thread:  http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=82359

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command to know how much free space currently available in your SQL Server 2000:

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(5000)   
DECLARE @DBInfo TABLE   
( ServerName VARCHAR(100),   
DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),   
PhysicalFileName NVARCHAR(520),   
FileSizeMB DECIMAL(10,2),   
SpaceUsedMB DECIMAL(10,2),   
FreeSpaceMB DECIMAL(10,2), 
FreeSpacePct varchar(8) 
) 

SELECT @command = 'Use [' + '?' + '] SELECT   
@@servername as ServerName,   
' + '''' + '?' + '''' + ' AS DatabaseName   , filename 
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round(a.size/128.000,2)) as FileSizeMB 
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(a.name,'+''''+'SpaceUsed'+''''+')/128.000,2)) as SpaceUsedMB 
    , convert(decimal(12,2),round((a.size-fileproperty(a.name,'+''''+'SpaceUsed'+''''+'))/128.000,2)) as FreeSpaceMB, 
    CAST(100 * (CAST (((a.size/128.0 -CAST(FILEPROPERTY(a.name,' + '''' + 'SpaceUsed' + '''' + ' ) AS int)/128.0)/(a.size/128.0)) AS decimal(4,2))) AS varchar(8)) + ' + '''' + '%' + '''' + ' AS FreeSpacePct 
from dbo.sysfiles a' 

INSERT INTO @DBInfo 
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @command   

SELECT * from @DBInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run SQL scripts to check free space manually. But it's better to create jobs and assign alerts to automatically inform admin, when not enough space left.

The best article I found - [Managing Database Data Usage With Custom Space Alerts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/alerts/89885/) (SQLServerCentral login is required) can be followed even by support personnel without much DBA experience.

You can also use similar article [Monitor database file sizes with SQL Server Jobs](http://m.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/monitor-database-file-sizes-with-sql-server-jobs/296).

Also for manual check I prefer **sp_SOS** (can be downloaded from
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Find-size-of-SQL-Server-tables-and-other-objects-with-stored-procedure)

```
EXEC dbo.sp_SOS @OrderBy='T'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited Michael Petrotta query to add free space percentage column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(volume_mount_point, 1, 1) AS volume_mount_point
    ,total_bytes/1024/1024 AS total_MB
    , available_bytes/1024/1024 AS available_MB
    ,((available_bytes/1024*1024) *100/(total_bytes/1024*1024)) as free_percent
FROM
    sys.master_files AS f
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, sql server always automatically allocated more space until the harddrive was full, so just query the free space on the harddrive.

What settings do you use that you have to increase the "space" of a database?

Comment: SQL Server maintains unused space within its data files.  When that free space runs out, SQL Server will grow the file to accommodate. Database performance could be affected during that growth.  I typically set the auto-grow size to something reasonable, given my data, and let it go at that.

Comment: A query about free space on the file system makes a lot of assumptions, particularly when when the data is easily available from SQL server. If the dba is aware of capacity trends then a growth script can do the job w/o affecting perf (the built-in feature almost certainly will affect perf).